# Share on pinterest using pinit button

Tags: html, pinterest

I have created a pinit button which can be seen here
http://auragraphic.com/mag/

for each image there is a pinit button, when I am clicking on it I pass following things

1. url - this contains the image url
2. media - this contains the image url
3. description - this contains text + short url for product

example link

```
http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://auragraphic.com/mag/gqlive/timberlandlook_1.jpg&media=http://auragraphic.com/mag/gqlive/timberlandlook_1.jpg&description=I%20love%20GQ%20Live%20products%20http://goo.gl/pFNcl
```

When I am visiting the above link I am getting a message from pinterest that
This pin contains a link or text that we do not allow. We have blocked this pin for your safety

May I know what is wrong in the above example link

Comment: the message is from Pinterest . Ask them.

Answer (score 0):

THis is happening because of the goo.gl shortener. I tried posting the same link without the shortening and it was posted successfully. So, either use some other whitelisted url shortener or use the complete link while sharing. Better option is to create your own url shortener using free URL shortener script from http://yourls.org/

Comment: did you tried posting it with complete link or short url from other services

Comment: I recommend using the full complete URL, shortening services have been known to change or even go out of business. You want the Googlejuice to flow.